# Lost GUI after installed GTK. Gets warning-"System running in low graphics mode"

Tags: unity, gui, gtk, glibc

am using ubuntu 14.4.0 64 bit. yesterday i installed GTK, Glibc and it's dependencies.
including,

- **libffi-dev,   libcairo2-dev,   libtiff-dev,   flex, bison,   xorg-dev,   libatk-bridge2.0**

finally installed glibc and GTK 3.10. [Edit:] Some were installed through the package manager, some from source with `./configure` and `make install` and I don't remember which belong to which category.

After i reboot i got a message box,

```
System running in Low Graphics mode
```

-> [Possibly copy of this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

i Have tried all installation and un-installation of packages, but doesn't work anything.
I have access to terminal. So i tried "**startx**". Now i got gui in a different way,

*1) it doesn't have close[X] or minimize[-] button. CTRL+Q is used to quit.(ALT-f4 doesn't work)
2) terminal can be opened by pressing ctrl+alt+T . but can't write anything
3) VLC media player can be opened but no Close button.*

i want to get my all data back. So am ready to install or uninstall anything. SO help me to get back my GUI.
i tried to,

> - install gdm
> - lightdm
> - nvdia-current
> - ubuntu-desktop

but after i reboot i get same warning "System running in low graphics mode"

i still remember, before when i installed GTK in fedora-20 i lost GUI. tried a lot. and shifted to Ubuntu. What is the problem with GTK. How can i get back my system.

Xorg.0.log

```
[  1007.314] 
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[  1007.316] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1007.317] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  1007.317] Current Operating System: Linux mrcracker-HP-2000-Notebook-PC 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64
[  1007.317] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[  1007.319] Build Date: 30 July 2014  12:21:54AM
[  1007.320] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  1007.320] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[  1007.322]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1007.322] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1007.324] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Sep 30 19:57:29 2014
[  1007.325] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1007.326] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1007.326] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1007.326] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1007.326] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1007.326] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1007.326] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1007.326] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1007.326] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1007.326] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1007.326]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1007.326] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  1007.326]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1007.326] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1007.326]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1007.326] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1007.326]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1007.326] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1007.326]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1007.326] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  1007.326] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1007.326] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1007.326] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fc8f0ec0d40
[  1007.326] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1007.326]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1007.326]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[  1007.326]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[  1007.326]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[  1007.326] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1007.327] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0166:103c:1854 rev 9, Mem @ 0xc2000000/4194304, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00004000/64
[  1007.328] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[  1007.329] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[  1007.329] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[  1007.330] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[  1007.331] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[  1007.332] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  1007.332] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[  1007.333] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[  1007.334] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[  1007.334] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[  1007.335] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[  1007.336] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[  1007.337] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[  1007.337] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[  1007.338] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[  1007.339] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[  1007.339] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  1007.340] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  1007.341] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[  1007.341] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[  1007.342] Initializing built-in extension Present
[  1007.343] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[  1007.344] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[  1007.344] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[  1007.345] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  1007.346] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[  1007.346] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  1007.347] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[  1007.347] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[  1007.348] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[  1007.348] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[  1007.348] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[  1007.348] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[  1007.348] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1007.348] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1007.349] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1007.349]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[  1007.349]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[  1007.349] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  1007.350] Loading extension GLX
[  1007.350] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1007.350] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1007.350] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[  1007.350] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[  1007.350] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[  1007.350] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1007.350] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[  1007.350] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[  1007.350] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1007.350]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 2.99.916
[  1007.350]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1007.350]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1007.350] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  1007.350] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  1007.350] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1007.350]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[  1007.350]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1007.350]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1007.350] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1007.351] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1007.351] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1007.351]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[  1007.351]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1007.351]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1007.351] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1007.351] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  1007.351] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1007.351]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[  1007.351]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1007.351]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1007.351] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[  1007.351] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[  1007.351] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[  1007.351] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[  1007.351] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  1007.351] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  1007.351] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  1007.351] (--) using VT number 7

[  1007.355] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20080730
[  1007.355] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.916+git20140915.d470f0f5-0ubuntu0sarvatt~trusty (Robert Hooker <sarvatt@ubuntu.com>)
[  1007.355] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[  1007.355] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  1007.355] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  1007.355] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  1007.355] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1007.355] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  1007.356] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1007.356]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[  1007.356]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[  1007.356] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[  1007.356] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
[  1007.356] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx
[  1007.356] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[  1007.356] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  1007.356] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[  1007.356] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 has no monitor section
[  1007.357] (--) intel(0): Found backlight control interface acpi_video0 (type 'firmware') for output LVDS1
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Enabled output LVDS1
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VGA1
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[  1007.357] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 64x64 for hardware cursors
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[  1007.357] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[  1007.357] (--) intel(0): Output LVDS1 using initial mode 1366x768 on pipe 0
[  1007.357] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[  1007.357] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  1007.357] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[  1007.357] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[  1007.358] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module dri3
[  1007.358] (II) UnloadModule: "dri3"
[  1007.358] (II) Unloading dri3
[  1007.358] (EE) intel: Failed to load module "dri3" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1007.358] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[  1007.358] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  1007.358] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[  1007.358] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[  1007.358] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[  1007.359] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module present
[  1007.359] (II) UnloadModule: "present"
[  1007.359] (II) Unloading present
[  1007.359] (EE) intel: Failed to load module "present" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1007.362] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  1007.362] (II) Unloading modesetting
[  1007.362] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  1007.362] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  1007.362] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  1007.362] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[  1007.362] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  1007.362] (II) Unloading vesa
[  1007.362] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[  1007.363] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Ivybridge (gen7, gt2) backend
[  1007.363] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[  1007.363] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[  1007.363] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[  1007.363] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[  1007.363] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[  1007.363] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[  1007.363] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[  1007.363] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: i965
[  1007.363] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[  1007.364] (==) intel(0): display hotplug detection enabled
[  1007.364] (--) RandR disabled
[  1007.371] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[  1007.375] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[  1007.375] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[  1007.377] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  1007.392] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 361 x 203
[  1007.405] (II) XKB: generating xkmfile /tmp/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[  1007.428] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[  1007.428] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1007.428] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[  1007.428] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[  1007.428] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1007.428]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.8.2
[  1007.428]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1007.428]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[  1007.429] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[  1007.429] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1007.429] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[  1007.429] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[  1007.429] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[  1007.429] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[  1007.429] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[  1007.429] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[  1007.429] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1007.429] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1007.429] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1007.430] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event6)
[  1007.430] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1007.430] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[  1007.430] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[  1007.430] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[  1007.430] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[  1007.430] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[  1007.430] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[  1007.430] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7/event6"
[  1007.430] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[  1007.430] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1007.430] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1007.430] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1007.431] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[  1007.431] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1007.431] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[  1007.431] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  1007.431] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[  1007.431] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[  1007.431] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[  1007.431] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[  1007.431] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[  1007.431] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[  1007.431] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1007.431] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1007.431] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1007.431] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[  1007.431] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1007.431] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1007.432] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0) card0 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
[  1007.432] (II) config/udev: Ignoring already known drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1007.432] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event10)
[  1007.432] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1007.432] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1007.433] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event9)
[  1007.433] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1007.433] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1007.433] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event8)
[  1007.433] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  1007.433] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  1007.433] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP Truevision HD (/dev/input/event7)
[  1007.433] (**) HP Truevision HD: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1007.433] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HP Truevision HD'
[  1007.433] (**) HP Truevision HD: always reports core events
[  1007.433] (**) evdev: HP Truevision HD: Device: "/dev/input/event7"
[  1007.433] (--) evdev: HP Truevision HD: Vendor 0x4f2 Product 0xb34f
[  1007.434] (--) evdev: HP Truevision HD: Found keys
[  1007.434] (II) evdev: HP Truevision HD: Configuring as keyboard
[  1007.434] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/input/input8/event7"
[  1007.434] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP Truevision HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[  1007.434] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1007.434] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1007.434] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1007.434] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[  1007.434] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1007.434] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[  1007.434] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[  1007.434] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[  1007.434] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[  1007.435] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[  1007.435] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[  1007.435] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[  1007.435] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[  1007.435] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1007.435] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1007.435] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1007.435] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event4)
[  1007.435] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[  1007.435] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[  1007.435] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[  1007.435] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[  1007.436] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[  1007.436] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1007.436]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 1.7.4
[  1007.436]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  1007.436]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[  1007.436] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[  1007.436] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[  1007.436] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[  1007.468] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: ignoring touch events for semi-multitouch device
[  1007.468] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1222 - 5734 (res 48)
[  1007.468] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 910 - 4974 (res 95)
[  1007.468] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[  1007.468] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[  1007.468] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left right double triple
[  1007.468] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[  1007.468] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  1007.468] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[  1007.480] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event4"
[  1007.480] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 11)
[  1007.480] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[  1007.480] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[  1007.480] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.033
[  1007.481] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  1007.481] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[  1007.481] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  1007.481] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  1007.481] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  1007.481] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[  1007.481] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[  1007.484] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP Wireless hotkeys (/dev/input/event5)
[  1007.484] (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1007.484] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HP Wireless hotkeys'
[  1007.484] (**) HP Wireless hotkeys: always reports core events
[  1007.484] (**) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[  1007.484] (--) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[  1007.484] (--) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Found keys
[  1007.484] (II) evdev: HP Wireless hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[  1007.484] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input6/event5"
[  1007.484] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP Wireless hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[  1007.484] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1007.484] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1007.484] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  1007.485] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event11)
[  1007.485] (**) HP WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1007.485] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HP WMI hotkeys'
[  1007.485] (**) HP WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[  1007.485] (**) evdev: HP WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event11"
[  1007.485] (--) evdev: HP WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[  1007.485] (--) evdev: HP WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[  1007.485] (II) evdev: HP WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[  1007.485] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input9/event11"
[  1007.485] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[  1007.485] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  1007.485] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1007.485] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
```

Comment: How did you install those packages? Were there any warnings about inconsistencies or removed packages? `apt-get` sometimes suggests to remove most of your desktop and system stack, if it resolves a dependency issue or conflict.

Comment: I installed using apt-get and some of them i downloded and issue   ./configure   command.doesn't get any warning. Thr problem started next time i boot the system

Comment: Hold on! You installed some of the software outside of the package manager? Then you need to provide a lot more details, what you installed in which order through which means, before anybody can meaningfully assess your situation. Please edit your question to include these infos.

Comment: A copy of your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` would also be very helpful.

Comment: i have updated.  And gtk, pango, cairo2 all installed from official site. and nvidia, ubuntu desktop, all installed frm apt-get. and actually i don't remember how i installed all. If any log file is there i will post it. Can i remove all desktop environment and install fresh? does that is the problem ?

Comment: I just noticed, that you said you use “Ubuntu 14.4.0“, which doesn't exist, but probably means Ubuntu 14.04. Then again the kernel version is 3.2.0-61-generic which doesn't add up, because the 14.04 is based on kernel version 3.13. Can you please run `sed -n 's/^DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=//p' /etc/lsb-release` and in accord with its output edit the Ubuntu release name in your question? After that run `uname -r`, and if the output is a version below 3.13, please reboot your machine into a 3.13-series kernel.

Comment: i reinstalled Ubuntu!!!!Now problem solved. But lost all data

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are running out of space in the root partiton. So check if sufficient space is available using

df -h

Free space can be made by removing temp files, unwanted documents, packages. Easiest way for you is to uninstall vlc by

sudo apt-get remove vlc

Comment: My /boot partition has only 8mp available. Always get warning. And  /root has 156gb free.   Does insufficient space in/ boot wil make problem?  How can i give more space?

Comment: I suspect you mean “8 MB”. That's a bit few space. You may want to have a look at “[How do I remove … old kernel versions](https://askubuntu.com/a/100953/175814)”. Please note that `/root` is not the same thing as the root directory `/`.